# Is $\{\mu\in P(X) : \int |x|^2 d\mu(x)\le C\}$ compact?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $X=\mathbb{R}^d$. I was wondering if the set $\{\mu\in P(X) : \int |x|^2 d\mu(x)\le C\}$ ($C$ is a constant), i.e. the set of probability measures with second moments smaller than $C$ was a compact space with respect to the weak-convergence. I want to be suspicious and say it is not but I am having a hard time coming up with an example of a sequence $(\mu_n)_{n\ge 1}$ of measures such that $\int |x|^2d\mu_n(x)\le C$ but doesn't have a weakly-converging subsequence.

Comment: You did not say what is $X$.  If $X$ is compact metric, then $P(X)$ is also compact metric; so in that case you need to determine whether your set is closed.

Comment: thanks, I edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will assume that $X$ is a complete separable metric space.

$\mu \{x: |x| >a\} \leq C\frac  1 {a^{2}}$, so the given family is tight. By prohorov's Theorem it is relatively compact. Suppose $\mu_n$ is  sequence of p.m.'s in the collection converging weakly to a p.m. $\mu$. Then $\int \min \{N, x^{2}\} d\mu =\lim \int \min \{N, x^{2}\} d\mu_n \leq C$ for all $N$ and letting $N \to \infty$ shows that your family is closed. Hence it is compact.

Comment: Would the space also be compact with respect to the p-Wasserstein distance? (up to which $p$?)

Comment: @roi_saumon nope